# Call to undefined method PaginatorComponent::paginate() cakephp2

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I'm upgrading my cakephp1.x project to cakephp2.10.12. I got below error when I try to apply pagination to my view

Error

Call to undefined method PaginatorComponent::paginate()

My controller code like this

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
class ProductsController extends AppController {
var $name = "Product";
var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form','Paginator','Js');
var $paginate = array('limit' => 25,'order' => array('Product.pname' => 'asc'));

function allproducts() { 

$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array("Product.status" => 'A','Product.stock >' => 0),
    );
$this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;

    list($order,$limit,$page) = $this->paginate(); // Added
```

Comment: * I got below error ...*  Where is it?  I do not see it in the question.

Comment: Why are you not following the documentation (https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html) and just paginate like this `$data = $this->Paginator->paginate('Product');` ?